# Magento Admin not working in WAMP

Tags: php

I installed a magento with sample data. Everything working fine. Only i am unable to login to admin.

When i access magento login page: at localhost/admin
Then it shows this normal magento login:

[image]

But after login it again shows a login page but with session key in url (which seems i login)

[image]

this is the url generated

```
http://localhost/index.php/admin/index/index/key/daa4f07e53bab68173031a1b566a6c87/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/f5af74af31bc336d09d1bff85da57625/?SID=napqsla40jor8f5kjvt4r27210
```

And when i modify this url to

```
http://localhost/admin/dashboard/index/key/f5af74af31bc336d09d1bff85da57625/?SID=napqsla40jor8f5kjvt4r27210
```

Then it shows actual dashboard but without loading js and html files. ONLY HTML version.

[image]

Any idea why it is doing like this?

Apache Rewrite enabled

Curl Enabled

Comment: File permissions?

Comment: File permission in wamp?

Comment: Looks like `url` is getting repeated twice! :P

Comment: Yes, URL is repeating twice and also files not loading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be 3 issues as far as my knowledge:

1. **Url issue:**

Check your secure base url and unsecure base url in 'core_config_data' table. It should be something like this:

```
http://localhost/your_project/
```

You can find this row in table whose path column value is `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

2. **Magento Cache issue:**

Go to `/your_project/var/cache` folder and delete all the contents. Clear browser cache as well and try reloading page.

3. **Php Curl Extension Issue:**

If you are using wamp server then check if you have enabled "php_curl" extension. If not, then enable it, restart wamp server and then try loading the page.

Comment: There is no base url row in core_config_data

Comment: @user2997826, see I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It look's like you have not set the good parameter for base_url.
Go on your database -> 'core_config_data' -> 'base_url' -> 'value'

Comment: There is no base url row in core_config_data

Comment: In 'path' row search web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url, then look the row 'value' for those path

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "localhost". 
Use

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

instead. 
(make sure you update base urls in DB too...)
Using localhost messes up cookies

Answer (score 1):

When using "localhost" with magento, don't use chrome browser as it can't make the cookie for localhost so that it again shows login page. Try to login admin on firebox.It works.